# How to find innerHtml(text) exceeds the container element width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to measure whether the text width inside a div exceeds the div width.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/92800cst/

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="breaking" >
            <label class="brNews">1318 Test - iPhone Start Page</label>
            <span>
            <div id="brContent">Test Content Title Which Exceeds the outer   element width to scroll</div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to scroll content(using marquee) inside the brContent div if the content exceeds the div, else I want to display the content as it is.

I don't want to calculate based on characters length of a text as we are using this in multiple devices.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; you cannot have a block element (`div`) nested inside an inline element (`span`). Also, your usage of `label` is incorrect here - I suspect what you need is a heading (`h1`- `h6`) tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById('breaking').querySelector('span');
(window.onresize = function log() {
  console.log("scrollWidth =", el.scrollWidth, ", clientWidth =", el.clientWidth);
})();
```

```css
#breaking {
  position: relative;
  background: #802018;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#breaking span {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 46px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#breaking label {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid #a8635a;
  background-color: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="breaking">
  <label class="brNews">1318 Test - iPhone Start Page</label>
  <span>Test Content Title Which Exceeds the outer element width to scroll</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#breaking span div').width() > $('#breaking').width())
{
   alert("exceded");
}else{
   alert("no exceded")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an height for the div which has the content.You can then give `overflow:auto`

CSS

```
#content{
  height:50px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/92800cst/1/) -->